# Visual Studio 2019 failed to update wwwroot folder content in Azure web app

Tags: azure, deployment, visual-studio-2019, azure-webapps

I have an Angular and C#/Dotnet Core 5.0 api application.  The C# code and Angular are in different folders.  I compiled angular code with ng build --prod.  Then I copied *.js files from angular dist to wwwroot folder in C# project, e.g. myapi/wwwroot.  After publishing from Visual Studio 2019 to Azure web app, the content of D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot does not get updated.  In the obj\Release\net5.0\PubTmp\Out\ I saw a wwwroot folder, but the content is old.  The new files from myapi/wwwroot folder is not copied over.  Any suggestions are really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please verify your cproj file and check if they're being excluded. You can add this to your csproj file to have the content of `wwwroot` copied over:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="wwwroot\**">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
   </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same/similar issue which was resolved by deleting the folders

projectroot/bin
projectroot/obj

please also set the file properties in solution explorer to "copy if newer" as shown in the image below

[image: file properties]